# How to plot a simple graph using batch script in xmgrace

Tags: xmgrace

I'm new to this topic and have no idea on how to write a batch script and plot the graph in xmgrace. Also, I have not found good examples which will guide me as a beginner to write such scripts.

What I have: A simple data file.

```
$ cat test_manual.dat
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
$
```

My Script:

```
$ cat first_file.bfile
arrange(6, 2, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2)
READ NXY "test_manual.dat"
WORLD XMIN 0
WORLD XMAX 5
WORLD YMIN 0
WORLD YMAX 5
s0 line color 1
title "Ten"
PRINT TO "first_file.agr"
PRINT
$
```

Please let me know what changes are required to make this file work and also help with any tutorial which will guide me through the advanced concepts as well.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise about what you want to do? Why do use the arrange function if you have only a single dataset?

Comment: I want to plot graphs using batch files. And I have no clue or didn't find a good tutorial to start with it. So expecting some examples or proper tutorial regarding the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to automatically create an agr file your batch file is almost fine. Just use this:

```
WORLD XMIN 0
WORLD XMAX 5
WORLD YMIN 0
WORLD YMAX 5
s0 line color 1
title "Ten"
SAVEALL "first_file.agr"
```

Note that, in order to make it print the agr file, you need to `xmgrace` (or `gracebat`) with the `-nosafe` argument, like this:

```
gracebat -nosafe -batch first_file.bfile
```

As far as I know there are no tutorials for creating batch files for `xmgrace`. What I usually do is to analyse agr files produced by xmgrace and copy the parts that I want to include in the batch files. The list of commands that can be used can be found [here](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Xmgr/doc/commands.html)